# Angular Error - You need to define an async loader such as requireJS or script.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and getting the following error and cant figure out why!

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module PaymentApp due to:
You need to define an async loader such as requireJS or script.js
```

I cant find any reference on the web either why I'm getting this!

Any idea?

Thanks

EDIT MORE CODE:

App.js

```
    'use strict';
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name PaymentApp
 * @description
 * # PaymentApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('PaymentApp', [
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar',
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$ocLazyLoadProvider',function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$ocLazyLoadProvider) {

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
      debug:false,
      events:true,
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard/home');

    $stateProvider
      .state('dashboard', {
        url:'/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/main.html',
        resolve: {
            loadMyDirectives:function($ocLazyLoad){
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                    name:'PaymentApp',
                    files:[
                    'scripts/directives/header/header.js',
                    'scripts/directives/header/header-notification/header-notification.js',
                    'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar.js',
                    'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar-search/sidebar-search.js'
                    ]
                }),
                $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                   name:'toggle-switch',
                   files:["bower_components/angular-toggle-switch/angular-toggle-switch.min.js",
                          "bower_components/angular-toggle-switch/angular-toggle-switch.css"
                      ]
                }),
                $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                  name:'ngAnimate',
                  files:['bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js']
                })
                $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                  name:'ngCookies',
                  files:['bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js']
                })
                $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                  name:'ngResource',
                  files:['bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js']
                })
                $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                  name:'ngSanitize',
                  files:['bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js']
                })
                $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                  name:'ngTouch',
                  files:['bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js']
                })
            }
        }
    })
      .state('dashboard.home',{
        url:'/home',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        templateUrl:'views/dashboard/home.html',
        resolve: {
          loadMyFiles:function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              name:'PaymentApp',
              files:[
              'scripts/controllers/main.js',
              'scripts/directives/timeline/timeline.js',
              'scripts/directives/notifications/notifications.js',
              'scripts/directives/chat/chat.js',
              'scripts/directives/dashboard/stats/stats.js'
              ]
            })
          }
        }
      })
      .state('dashboard.form',{
        templateUrl:'views/form.html',
        url:'/form'
    })
      .state('dashboard.blank',{
        templateUrl:'views/pages/blank.html',
        url:'/blank'
    })
      .state('login',{
        templateUrl:'views/pages/login.html',
        url:'/login'
    })
      .state('dashboard.chart',{
        templateUrl:'views/chart.html',
        url:'/chart',
        controller:'ChartCtrl',
        resolve: {
          loadMyFile:function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              name:'chart.js',
              files:[
                'bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js',
                'bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css'
              ]
            }),
            $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name:'PaymentApp',
                files:['scripts/controllers/chartContoller.js']
            })
          }
        }
    })
      .state('dashboard.table',{
        templateUrl:'views/table.html',
        url:'/table'
    })
      .state('dashboard.panels-wells',{
          templateUrl:'views/ui-elements/panels-wells.html',
          url:'/panels-wells'
      })
      .state('dashboard.buttons',{
        templateUrl:'views/ui-elements/buttons.html',
        url:'/buttons'
    })
      .state('dashboard.notifications',{
        templateUrl:'views/ui-elements/notifications.html',
        url:'/notifications'
    })
      .state('dashboard.typography',{
       templateUrl:'views/ui-elements/typography.html',
       url:'/typography'
   })
      .state('dashboard.icons',{
       templateUrl:'views/ui-elements/icons.html',
       url:'/icons'
   })
      .state('dashboard.grid',{
       templateUrl:'views/ui-elements/grid.html',
       url:'/grid'
   })
  }]);
```

And then the view (im using asp.net) that loads this app is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/App/styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/App/styles/sb-admin-2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/App/styles/timeline.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.2.0/metisMenu.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.8.0/loading-bar.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.8.0/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.0.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.2.0/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>



    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="~/App/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <!-- <link href="styles/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="PaymentApp">
        <div ui-view></div>

        <div id="contents" ng-view ng-cloak translate-cloak>
            <!-- Checkout: start-->
            @RenderBody()
            <!-- Checkout: end -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This error usually means angular can't find an object you are trying to inject into a controller or some other injectable function. You need to post more of your code if you want more specific help....

Comment: ok thanks, I have no reference to requireJS in my code anywhere, do i need to have a reference to this? Or hook this up as a module to the app itself somehow?  I have edited my response with some of the code.. hopefully thats enough